# DNS over HTTPS .. problems... doesn't "hide" really

Tags: domain-name-system, https

I am tring to setup an DNS over HTTPS. based on Debian 12 with Apache and DNSCrypt-proxy I wish for many PC on the same LAN, be able to use DNS Over https

My apache is really simple :

```
Protocols h2 http/1.1 
proxypass / http://127.0.2.1:53 
proxypassReverse / http://127.0.2.1:53 
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/ssl2024/example_net.crt 
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/ssl2024/foo_private.key 
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/ssl2024/xxxValidationSecureServerCA.crt 
SSLEngine on
```

and my DNScrypt-proxy

cat /etc/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-proxy.toml

```
listen_addresses = [] 
server_names = ['google'] 
doh_servers = true 
max_clients = 250 ipv4_servers = true dnscrypt_servers = true
#keepalive = 30 #ignore_system_dns = true
[doh_client_x509_auth]
    creds = [ { server_name='example.com', client_cert='/etc/ssl/example_com.crt', clientkey='/etc/ssl/exampleprivate.key' } ]
#dnssec = true [query_log] file = '/var/log/dnscrypt-proxy/query.log'
[nx_log] file = '/var/log/dnscrypt-proxy/nx.log'
[sources] 
    [sources.'public-resolvers'] url = 'https://download.dnscrypt.info/resolvers-list/v2/public-resolvers.md' cache_file = '/var/cache/dnscrypt-proxy/public-resolvers.md' minisign_key = 'RWQf6LRCGA9i53mlYecO4IzT51TGPpvWucNSCh1CBM0QTaLn73Y7GFO3' refresh_delay = 72 prefix = ''

[static]

    [static.'plan9dns-nj-doh']
    stamp = 'sdns://AgcAAAAAAAAADTIwNy4yNDYuODcuOTYgmjo09yfeubylEAPZzpw5-PJ92cUkKQHCurGkTmNaAhkUa3Jvbm9zLnBsYW45LWRucy5jb20KL2Rucy1xdWVyeQ'

    [static.'scaleway-ams']
    stamp = 'sdns://AQcAAAAAAAAADTUxLjE1LjEyMi4yNTAg6Q3ZfapcbHgiHKLF7QFoli0Ty1Vsz3RXs1RUbxUrwZAcMi5kbnNjcnlwdC1jZXJ0LnNjYWxld2F5LWFtcw'
```

IF I make a test and write 'curl -v --doh-url https://example.com/dns-query https://www.hotmail.com'

that seems to be OK

```
SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384   
ALPN: server accepted h2
Server certificate:
subject: CN=example.com
start date: Dec 20 00:00:00 2023 GMT
expire date: Jan 15 23:59:59 2025 GMT
subjectAltName: host "example.com" matched cert's "example.com"
issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=Sectigo Limited; CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
SSL certificate verify ok.
using HTTP/2
[HTTP/2] [1] OPENED stream for https://example.com/dns-query
[HTTP/2] [1] [:method: POST]
[HTTP/2] [1] [:scheme: https]
[HTTP/2] [1] [:authority: example.com]
[HTTP/2] [1] [:path: /dns-query]
[HTTP/2] [1] [accept: /]
[HTTP/2] [1] [content-type: application/dns-message]
[HTTP/2] [1] [content-length: 27]
POST /dns-query HTTP/2 Host: example.com 
Accept: / Content-Type: application/dns-message Content-Length: 27 ..... ( No error message )
```

a dig @127.0.0.1 hotmail.com

dig @127.0.0.1 hotmail.com
;; communications error to 204.79.197.212#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 204.79.197.212#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 204.79.197.212#53: connection refused

dig +https @127.0.0.1 hotmail.com

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.19-1~deb12u1-Debian <<>> +https @127.0.0.1 hotmail.com ; (1 server found) 
;; global options: +cmd ;; Got answer: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47464 
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION: ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232 ; COOKIE: beb1bfe6ee58993a01000000658ac298da5e778ac1e11be6 (good) 
;; QUESTION SECTION: ;hotmail.com.          IN  A
;; ANSWER SECTION: hotmail.com.     3600    IN  A   204.79.197.212
;; Query time: 124 msec 
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#443(127.0.0.1) (HTTPS) 
;; WHEN: Tue Dec 26 13:10:00 CET 2023 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 84
```

Globally, that sounds to be OK

And Bind9.18 "option" is

```
    tls local-tls {
        key-file "/etc/bind/example.key";
        cert-file "/etc/bind/ST_example_net.crt";
        dhparam-file "/etc/bind/dhparam.pem";
};
http local {
    # multiple paths can be specified
    endpoints { "/dns-query";  };
};
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
//listen-on port 53 {any;};
//listen-on-v6 port 53 {any;};
    allow-recursion {any;};
    # default ports for HTTP and HTTPS
    http-port 80;
    https-port 443;
    dnssec-validation auto;

};
```

but if I use an Internet explorer , select DoH with my own : https://example.com/dns-query Then Seems not to work with the error message Possible security risk looking up this domain even with famous ones.... I need to use DOH

Any idea ? What other test I should do ? thanks for your help

I've tried all the combination that I found on Internet... no success.. The question is how a frame from https can be sent to dnscrypt-proxy ?

Which other test should I do ? To which direction should I look for ?

In fact, I had a look with wireshark. That seems to be correctly encrypted on the "https" side.. The point is that the server is on a LAN I need to encrypt on the other side. Any request forwarding to Cloudflare or NextDNS via DNSCrypt-proxy seems not to be encrypted and surprisingly, I can see the request on the Port 53 UDP. But I configured nothing with bind9 on forwarding IP address. I don't know where comes from these UDP on port 53 :-( from my server to google or nextDNS Thanks for your help

In other words, what I am looking for is: any rquest from our LAN ( via bind on https..) should go out to the WAN ONLY via DNS Over Https.. ' I should see only TCP, TLS frames on Wireshark.. no ?